# "f was unexpected at this time" - bash script

Tags: bash, stanford-nlp

I am currently trying to use the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline to run sentiment analysis. I need it to iterate through a folder of individual text files (which contain movie reviews) in order to establish the sentiment of each review.  I have tried to create a batch script in order to iterate through the 3 different folders containing the reviews.  when running the script through the shell runner program i receive the following error:

**f was unexpected at this time**

the script is as follows:

```
dir=C:\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31
for f in "$dir\train\neg" && 
    for f in "$dir\train\pos" && 
        for f in "$dir\train\unsup" ; do
    echo $f >> filelist.txt
    java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath filelist.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz 
done
```

this is the first bash script i have ever written so I am assuming my syntax is possibly incorrect somewhere?

Also I am using Windows 10.

Any advice would be amazing,

many thanks

hey guys your advice has been extremely useful.  to try and make my life a bit easier I have tried to convert my script to a batch script so that it shouldnt have any issues with being run on windows.  my new script looks as follows:

```
        @echo off
dir=C:\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31
for %%f in "%dir\train\neg" & "%dir\train\pos" & "%dir\train\unsup" do
    ECHO %%f >> filelist.txt
    java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath filelist.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz 
done
pause
```

which results in the following error:
"%dir\train\pos" was unexpected at this time

anyone understand what i've done wrong? I'm assuming it's some sort of a syntax issue I just can't see it.

Comment: I'm sure that's not a batch file. In batch variables are set by [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command and are used by `%var%`, not `$var` like in bash. And [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) doesn't end with `done`. There's no `;` in batch either (actually yes but it doesn't end a statement)

Comment: So you are using the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: Sorry I shouldve explained a bit better, I am using Windows 10 but I have installed cygwin in order to be able to use linux commands for more flexibility with my bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multiple for's you can put all the items after the first like this:

```
 for f in "$dir\train\neg" "$dir\train\pos" "$dir\train\unsup" ; do
```

Or even:

```
for f in "$dir\train\"{neg,pos,unsup}
do
    ....
done
```

Also, I would think you would need to replace all single slashes "\" with two  "\\". but can't say for sure as I don't have Windows.

So it might be

```
 dir=C:\\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

 for f in "$dir\\train\\"{neg,pos,unsup}
 do
     ...
 done
```

Its unclear whether:

- you need to call Java 3 times ( once for each dir)

Or:

- you need to put all 3 dirs in filelist.txt  and then call Java at the end

Example to call Java 3 times with only one dir in filelist.txt each time:

```
 for f in "$dir\\train\\"{neg,pos,unsup}
 do 
     #note this ">" will over-write the file each time
     echo "$f" > filelist.txt  
     java    .... filelist.txt
 done
```

Creating a list file with 3 directories then call Java once:

```
 # note this ">" will overwrite the file with nothing
 # so it will then be empty
 # so that it doesn't have what's left over from last time
 # that you ran the script
 > filelist.txt  

 for f in "$dir\\train\\"{neg,pos,unsup}
 do
      #note this ">>" will add a line to the file
      echo "$f" >> filelist.txt  
 done

 # call Java after you've finished creating the file
 java ..... filelist.txt
```

that you need

But, you don't even need the loop (assuming you have the 'ls' command available to you in that environment)

```
dir=C:\\stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

ls -1 -d "$dir\\train\\"{neg,pos,unsup} > filelist.txt

java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath filelist.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

NOTE 
The {neg,pos,unsup}
syntax will work in bash but not in a windows bat file

Comment: thanks for the comments, I have taken all advice but to no avail.  i think i may have possibly done something else wrong, or maybe this isnt possible on my system :(

Comment: Unless you installed "cygwin" I would think it's not!   'Bash'  is a scripting language for Linux and Unix and Mac.    (And installing Cygwin provides it on Windows).  You can do what you need with a "bat" script in windows.  However did you consider you can create the filelist.txt with a text editor (notepad.exe) and past the folder names into it and then you can have a .bat file with just your Java command inside it, and then doubleclick on that

Comment: Oh you do have cygwin.just saw that above. What error message are you getting now?

Comment: Did you type the commands in a terminal or in a script file and then ran the file? Because bash error is "syntax error near unexpected token &&" but you got "f was unexpected".   You may not be running it in bash

Comment: If you typed bash code but put it in a file called something.bat then when you run it it will be run as a windows batch script , not as a bash script.     Try making sure the file has the extension ".sh" that may help

Comment: hey guys your advice has been extremely useful.  to try and make my life a bit easier I have tried to convert my script to a batch script so that it shouldnt have any issues with being run on windows.  my new script looks as follows:

Comment: Hey, its not working because {neg,pos,unsup} would only work in bash.  In a bat file you might need to put each one separately, like for %%f in %dir\train\pos %dir\train\neg %dir\train\unsup

Comment: And with bat scripts you can use.  C:\  without the extra \

Comment: Thank you so much Chunko you are being super helpful.  I think my issue is that I'm getting confused with my syntax due to being a beginner.  I have edited my initial question to show the alterations and further issues I'm having.  If you can see the problem please let me know :D